# No sooner did subject present or No sooner had subject part perticiple

Tags: grammar

> - As soon as he came into the classroom, the light went off.
> - No sooner had he come into the classroom than the light went off.
> - No sooner did he come into the classroom than the light went off.

Which is right? If I use the first, is that right?

Comment: They are all right. 2 and 3 have a slightly different emphasis. Generally, the past perfect is better with "no sooner than".

Answer (score 1):

All three of these sentences are grammatical and have the same meaning. Astralbee is incorrect in using "came" rather than "come" - "had come" is the correct past perfect tense, which is made up of a past tense auxiliary verb + past participle main verb (which in this case is "come". Sometimes the past participle is the same as the past tense; just not in this case).

Comment: Your explanation is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tense of your verb. If the verb is present tense then use "did"; if it is past tense then use "had":

> No sooner **did** he **come** into the classroom than the light went off.

or

> No sooner **had** he **came** into the classroom than the light went off.

Comment: Sorry, if the verb is present tense, use "did"? That does not make sense here.